# Using char ** where new elements overwriting previous elements

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

```
char ** Ptr;
char apple[15];
char cake[15];
Ptr = new char*[2];

Ptr[0]=apple;
Ptr[1]=cake;
```

Unfortunately after updating `Ptr[1]`, `Ptr[0]` becomes `cake` in addition to `Ptr[1]`. I am pretty sure the problem is how I declared `Ptr` I essentially wanted it to be an array of strings. Is there a way to do this where I keep `char ** Ptr`?

**Edit:**

```
{
char **Ptr;
{
char apple[15];
Ptr = new char*[2];
for(int k=0;k<2;k++)
{
memset(apple,0,15);
//apple=
Ptr[k]=apple; //Note that apple in fact changes everytime
}
//Originally I had Ptr[k]=apple but it seemed I was merely copying the address of  
//apple which works great except when I leave the scope trying to call it the addr no 
//longer exists and I was getting lucky the last entry showed up at all. So I then 
//figured I would use

strcpy(Ptr[k],apple);

//I then checked the value for both was correct even when I deleted apple.
// Finally I leave the scope where all this is taking place
}
cout<<Ptr[0];
cout<<Ptr[1];
}
```

Luckily they were in fact equivalent garbage. First few chars were the same but mostly garbage. I thought maybe was scope issue with `Ptr` so basically made it global same problem. Anyways I left the original problem even though it didn't contain any problems as everyone was so kind to point out because I had made the separate variable `cake` (woops). Any help would be greatly appreciated though.

Regardless, thanks for your time.

Comment: [Works fine here](http://ideone.com/nKTsd7).

Comment: Can you show us exactly how you are dereferencing `Ptr` to view its contents?

Comment: Problem is not here obviously

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even after your edit it is still not very clear what you mean, especially since it seems that you do understand what pointers and scopes are.

> longer exists and I was getting lucky the last entry showed up at all. So I then
> figured I would use
>
> ```
> strcpy(Ptr[k],apple);
> ```

If you use `strcpy` like this, then you must allocate the memory for *every* `Ptr[k]` on the heap, and your code will work just fine.

However, since you are coding in C++, it's better to stick to C++ features. Namely, instead of allocating arrays of `chars` and pointers to `chars`, which is a C approach, use the following:

```
vector<string> Ptr;
{
    string apple;
    for(int k=0;k<2;k++)
    {
        //apple=
        Ptr.push_back(apple);
    }
}
cout<<Ptr[0];
cout<<Ptr[1];
```

Here I left the names of the variables and the code structure to be the same for clarity, although `Ptr` is obviously not a pointer any longer.

Answer (score -3):

Use `Ptr = malloc(sizeof(char *) * 2);` in replace of `Ptr = new char*[2];`